# How to return Int value to ON_BN_CLICKED

Tags: c++, mfc

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, OnHolNameOK)
ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_BTN_HOLCAL_NEW, OnBtnHolcalNew)
```

How to return `int` or `bool` to `on_bn_clicked function`?

```
BOOL CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew() 
SINT4 CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalDelete() 


BOOL CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew() 
{
    DBUG_ENTER("CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew");

    SINT4 nCount = 0;

    CCreateHolCalDlg dlgCreateHolCal;

    if(IDOK == dlgCreateHolCal.DoModal())           
    {
        this->UpdateList();
        nCount = m_lbHolCal.GetItemCount();
        m_lbHolCal.SetItemState((nCount-1), LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED);
        m_lbHolCal.EnsureVisible((nCount-1), FALSE);
        this->UpdateStatusForDeleteBtn();
        DBUG_RETURN(TRUE);
    }
    else
       DBUG_RETURN(FALSE);
}

SINT4 CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalDelete() 
{   
    DBUG_ENTER("CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalDelete");

    SINT4 nItem;
    SINT4 nState = 0;
    CString pszCode;

    nItem = m_lbHolCal.GetNextItem( -1, LVNI_SELECTED );
    if(nItem >= 0)
    {
        pszCode = m_lbHolCal.GetItemText(nItem, 1); 
    }

    if (nState = DeleteCalendar((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)pszCode))
    {
        errReport(SEVERITY_FATAL, CMOI_DELETE_HOLIDAY_CALENDAR_ERROR, nState);
        GiveErrorDialog(this->m_hWnd, IDS_ERR_HOLCAL_DELETE,
            "", "", IDS_DLG_HC_DELETE, 
            CMOI_DELETE_HOLIDAY_CALENDAR_ERROR,
            nState);
        CDialog::OnCancel();
        DBUG_RETURN(nState);
    }
    this->UpdateList();

    DBUG_RETURN(SUCCESS);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAddHolCalDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_BTN_HOLCAL_NEW, OnBtnHolcalNew)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_BTN_HOLCAL_OPEN, OnBtnHolcalOpen)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_BTN_HOLCAL_DELETE, OnBtnHolcalDelete)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_CLICK, ID_LIST_HOLCAL, OnListItemClick)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_RCLICK, ID_LIST_HOLCAL, OnListItemRightClick)
```

SINT4 CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalDelete() 
in this function we are returning the state from function.
BOOL CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew() 
In this we are capturing return value from the function.

The above code used to work in Visual Studio 6.0.
We had this version of code being executed in customer site as well.

Please help me. How to achieve this in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: You cannot return a value from an OnButtonHandler, it doesn't make any sense. Who would use this returned value anyway? Such a handler must be a void function (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-button-handlers?view=vs-2019)). I don't know how this could have compiled in Visual Studio 6. You need to show us more code if you want help.

Comment: I pasted function definition. Please help me out

Comment: Read my first comment carefully. You cannot return a value from an On button handler. It's wrong. It doesn't make sense. What is that value return from the on button handler used for? Who uses this value?

Comment: What is `DBUG_RETURN`?

Comment: I seriously don't have solid understanding on onbuttonhandler. DEBUG_RETURN returns either success or failure. If it can not return anything other than void how it is working with VS 6.0. we build it yesterday to cross check whether it is working or not, but it is working.

Comment: Don't describe what `DEBUG_RETURN` is but show the exact definition. I need to know in order to make sense out of this.

Comment: Do you think it is useless to use any return have other than void for on button handler?

Comment: Not only useless, but plain wrong. Please show the definition of `DEBUG_RETURN` so I can make sens out of all this and write an answer.

Comment: define DBUG_RETURN(a1) return(((_local_db_in_trace)?DBUG_LEAVE0:(void)0),(a1))

Comment: And what is `DBUG_LEAVE0`?

Answer (score 0):

As the [Microsoft documentatioon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-button-handlers) states, button handlers are `void` functions.

So it is pretty unclear how Visual Studio 6 could have compiled this without errors.

It's also unclear what exactly `DBUG_RETURN` does as you didn't provide all the necessary information. It seems to do some diagnostic logs.

Anyway your button handlers should look like this:

```
void CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew() 
{
    DBUG_ENTER("CAddHolCalDlg::OnBtnHolcalNew");

    SINT4 nCount = 0;

    CCreateHolCalDlg dlgCreateHolCal;

    if(IDOK == dlgCreateHolCal.DoModal())           
    {
        this->UpdateList();
        nCount = m_lbHolCal.GetItemCount();
        m_lbHolCal.SetItemState((nCount-1), LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED);
        m_lbHolCal.EnsureVisible((nCount-1), FALSE);
        this->UpdateStatusForDeleteBtn();
        // add your logging stuff here
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // add your logging stuff here
       return;
    }
}
```